# PostgreSQL equivalent of IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have the following SQL query (in C# string SqlCommand command format) which will attempt to UPDATE a record and if it doesn't exist then INSERT instead.

```
string query = @"UPDATE [schemaX].[tableY] SET
                GUID = @GUID,
                Platform = @Platform,
                Email = @Email
                WHERE Email = @Email AND Platform = @Platform

                IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO [schemaX].[tableY]
                (
                    GUID,
                    Platform,
                    Email
                )
                Values
                (
                    @GUID,
                    @Platform,
                    @Email
                )";
```

tableY Columns:

```
Id:int (Primary Key auto increment)
Email: string
GUID:string
Platform:string
```

I'm trying to convert this to PostgreSQL query (NpgsqlCommand command)

There seems to be many suggestions of using UPSERT ON CONFLICT or WHERE NOT EXISTS but I can't see how I can use it in this case as I never know or set the Primary key field Id to determine if there is a CONFLICT, the Id is an auto generated field. PostgreSQL seems to check the INSERT conflict first rather than an UPDATE.

How would I do this in PostgreSQL?

For example, the query below creates multiple records instead of updating an existing record with the same email,platform

Note: Ideally I could change the GUID to be the primary key and get it working but I cannot change the table in this case for other reasons.

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO ""schemaX"".""tableY""
                (
                    ""GUID"",
                    ""Platform"",
                    ""Email""
                )
                Values
                (
                    @GUID,
                    @Platform,
                    @Email

                )
                ON CONFLICT (""Id"") DO
                UPDATE SET
                ""GUID"" = @GUID,
                ""Platform"" = @Platform,
                ""Email"" = @Email
                WHERE ""schemaX"".""tableY"".""Email"" = @Email AND ""schemaX"".""tableY"".""Platform"" = @Platform";
```

Comment: I can't change the table design unfortunately. I'm stuck with a auto generated PK and no unique indexes but still have to INSERT/UPDATE on unique email,platform combinations.

Comment: Your original query suggests that you want `ON CONFLICT ("Email", "Platform")` (because those fields are used in the `UPDATE`'s `WHERE` condition). This will require (of course) a unique costraint/index on `("Email", "Platform")`. -- Also: settings those fields in the `UPDATE`'s `SET` clause won't do anything, so you can just omit them in both of your variants.

Comment: @pozs - I did try that originally but get an error as there is no constraints on those two columns. The error is `Npgsql.PostgresException: 42P10: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`

Comment: @pathDongle yes, the constraint (or at least a unique index) is needed, because what you want to achieve is uniqueness (even in the face of high concurrency). if you don't want to achieve uniqueness, you could just use plain `INSERT`s.

Comment: @pozs - okay thanks I see what I need to do now. If you add that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original query's PostgreSQL equivalent is:

```
INSERT INTO "schemaX"."tableY" ("GUID", "Platform", "Email")
  VALUES (@GUID, @Platform, @Email)
  ON CONFLICT ("Platform", "Email")
  DO UPDATE SET "GUID" = EXCLUDED."GUID"
```

You don't need to update `"Platform"` and `"Email"` as they define the uniqueness, you want to achieve (so, if the `ON CONFLICT` branch is reached, there is already a row in your table with the exact same values). You also don't need the predicate for `DO UPDATE`: it will be true anyway **because** of this uniqueness. The `EXCLUDED` "row" is a simple way to avoid repeating the query parameter. It is even more important, when your `UPSERT` is based on an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement.

However, PostgreSQL will require a unique constraint (or at least a unique index) on `("Platform", "Email")` in order to guarantee this query's success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EXISTS` clause to do this as well:

```
INSERT INTO [schemaX].[tableY] (  GUID,  Platform,  Email )
VALUES                         ( @GUID, @Platform, @Email )
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    [schemaX].[tableY]
    WHERE   Email = @Email
    AND     Platform = @Platform
);
```